# Primes and certain unit fractions

Tags: prime-numbers, fractions

Are there primes $p,q$ and a natural number $a$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{a}$?

Answer (score 26):

Only for $p=q=2$. Indeed, if it is the case, then
$$\frac{p+q}{pq}=\frac1a$$
and $p+q$ divides $pq$. But only $1$, $p$, $q$ and $pq$ divide $pq$. Certainly $p+q$ is not any of the three first numbers. The other possibility is
$$p+q=pq$$
But in this case,
$$(p-1)(q-1)=pq-p-q+1=1$$
Therefore, $p=q=2$.

Comment: Possible simplification: Assume both p and q are odd.  Then pq is odd and p + q is even.  Assume one is odd and the other is even (i.e. equal to 2).  Then p + q is odd and pq is even.  Both cases have an odd number equal to an even number, which doesn't work.  Thus, p and q are both even, and 2 is the only even prime.